# New column to store results of running count

Tags: r

I have a data frame that begins:

```
id treatment
1  B
2  B
3  A
4  A
```

I aim to add a column to the data frame.

Each entry in the new column should be the total number of "A" values in the Treatment column up to and including the row of the entry.

For example, the new column should display 1 for the third row of the data frame (please see above) and 2 for the fourth row (please see above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running counts can be handled with the `cumsum` function:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=1:4, treatment=c("B", "B", "A", "A"))
cumsum(dat$treatment == "A")
# [1] 0 0 1 2
```

This is taking the cumulative sum of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values, which are converted to values 1 and 0, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

to complete josilber's answer, say you want to know the number of As up to and including row `myRow`, just invoke: `cumsum(dat$treatment == "A")[myRow]`

Comment: The OP is asking to add a column to the data frame, so probably better to use something like `dat$numA <- cumsum(dat$treatment == "A")`.